# Solving a Bernoulli ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem is taken from Riley, Hobson, Bence - "Mathematical Methods in Physics and Engineering". I have a different answer from what is presented and don't know why.

Solve: $$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=2x^{3}y^{4}$$

Rearranged into linear ODE form using $v = y^{1-n}$ = $y^{-3}$:
$$\frac{dv}{dx} - \frac{3v}{x} = -6x^{3}$$

Integration factor (I(x) or I) calculated as: $I(x) = \frac{1}{x^{3}}$

Multiplying ODE through by I(x):
$$\frac{1}{x^{3}} \frac{dv}{dx} - \frac{1}{x^{3}} \frac{3v}{x} = -6$$

Integrating directly I get:
$$\int \frac{1}{x^{3}} \frac{dv}{dx} dx - \int \frac{3v}{x^{4}}dx = \int-6dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{x^{3}}dv + \frac{v}{x^{3}} = -6x+c$$
$$\frac{v}{x^{3}} + \frac{v}{x^{3}} = -6x+c$$
$$\frac{2v}{x^{3}} = -6x+c$$
'y' can be substituted back into the last equation, and then after some rearranging the y(x) function can be found. In the textbook, the final equation into which 'y' is subbed into is: $$\frac{v}{x^{3}} = -6x + c$$

What is the error in my working?

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{x^{3}}dv \neq \frac{v}{x^{3}}$ Same goes for $ \int \frac{3v}{x^{4}}dx$

Comment: Understood. What would be the correct evaluations of those integrals?

Comment: which problem number/chapter from the book? There are some solved problems from this book [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/solving_ODE/current_version/inch12.htm#inse105.htm) may be this problem is there.

Comment: It is in Chapter 14, but it isn't an exercise from the problem set, it is one given to demonstrate the general method for solving a Bernoulli ODE. Unfortunately not many steps are shown in book (only rearranging into Linear form and results of the final integration), so I cannot see where I made my error. Thanks for the link though, will use if need to in future 

Comment: Solved update: used reverse process with product rule to calculate which function products could produce the differential equation calculated.

Comment: Book is correct, Just solved it and got book answer. What you did after finding integrating factor looks wrong.

Comment: Yes sir, v is a function of y, and y is a function of x, so I can't treat v as a constant in the integration with respect to x, so that step was incorrect.